# <img src=...> does not display local images in WordPress header.php and index.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image, href

I am trying to use a simple `<img src=` tag to link to a favicon.ico in my header.php file and a .png logo in my index.php file in my WordPress theme, but without any luck. I've tested the link by replacing it with a hyperlink to an image hosted online, which works and proves that the `<img src=` tag isn't broken, but obviously I would prefer to be able to have the images linked within an internal img folder in the theme. The background image I have used in my site (which is linked in the bootstrap.css and is in the same 'img' folder as the two images I am trying to link to) works perfectly. I've tried copying the formatting of that href link but it doesn't seem to work either.

I've tried many variations of `'img/favicon.ico'`, `'/img/favicon.ico'`, `'../img/favicon.ico'` but none of them worked to link to the image files in both cases.

Here is my code for the header.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package wpbootstrap-sofa
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="icon" href='../img/favicon.ico'>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->


<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->


<!-- Custom styles for this template -->


<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="background">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">home</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">store</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
```

And here is the code for the index.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package wpbootstrap-sofa
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="starter-template">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="center-block">
            <a href="index.html">
                    <img src='../img/sofa-logo.png' class="img-responsive center-block" alt="UQ SoFA logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.center-block -->
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/" target="_blank">store</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 -->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">SoFA at Market Day</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Cut Thumb ARI</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">GoMA Talks</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Interview with...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Lecture by...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">Post #474</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row-->
</div>
<!-- /.starter-template-->

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.background -->


<?php
get_footer();?>
```

[Linked here is a screenshot of the configuration of my theme's folders, including the 'img' folder where the images are contained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNJYj.jpg).

Any help that could be provided would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any error messages?

Comment: The path to the file is relative to location of the PHP file. Change "../" to "./"

Comment: do you close body and html in footer?

Comment: @SloanThrasher ./ and ../  are very different if i want to go root folder and navigate from there  then i use ./../folder1 "../" means up 1 level in the folder

Comment: @Gert Yeah, I definitely have he body and html closed in my footer

`<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package wpbootstrap-sofa
 */

?>
<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <p class="text-muted">&copy; UQ Society of Fine Art 2017 | Site by Patrick Hansen</p>
 </div>
</footer>

</div>
<!-- /.background -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
`

Comment: for index.php src='img/sofa-logo.png'

Comment: I have got the sofa-logo.png to display in my index.php using the method that Alexandre suggested, however, I still can't get the favicon.ico to display in the header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using the method Alexandre suggested and then changing `<link rel="icon`" to `<link rel="shortcut icon"`

Answer (score 6):

Please use it as follow :--

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/favicon.ico">
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: This works for the issue with the logo in my index.php, but not for the favicon in my header.php. Any suggestions? This is what my code looks like after trying your suggestion:

`<link rel="icon" <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/favicon.ico">`

Have I formatted this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are better to use automatic path, if your image is in your template directory for example :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/img/favicon.ico" />
```

You have to remember that the path is relative to the website address, when using `/path/to/file`, this will be absolute from the domain, so from the root in the website on server side. When using `path/to/file`, it will be relative to the web page, not the PHP file. This means if you have `http://example.com/category/page`, the server will try to find `<websiteroot>/category/page/path/to/file`.

Comment: This works for the issue with the logo in my index.php, but not for the favicon in my header.php. Any suggestions? This is what my code looks like after trying your suggestion:

`<link rel="icon" <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/img/favicon.ico" />`

Have I formatted this incorrectly?

Comment: Well, is the favicon.ico inside the directory img inside directory of your template? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: The favicon.ico is in the directory 'img' inside the directory of my template, yes. The complete directory for the favicon.ico file is:

/public_html/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap-sofa/img/favicon.ico

Comment: I've addressed the issue by using <link rel="shortcut icon" as opposed to using <link rel="icon" but with the solution you suggested